# how to configure config.inc.php to have a loginform in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Do I have to download any files in order to have a login form in `php`. I've asked this a million times but I'm not sure if you guys gets the question or not. All I want is a login form In `phpmyadmin`. Wherein you will input your username and password. DO I have to create any `php` login form or is it already included when you install `wampserver`. I've already configured the `config.inc.php` in `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1` . 
Here is what it looks like when I don't include any password. What do I have to edit? I'm beginner and so eager to have that login form already but I don't get any relevant answers.

```
<?php

    /* Servers configuration */
    $i = 0;

    /* Server: localhost [1] */
    $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

    /* End of servers configuration */

    $cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
    $cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
    $cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
    $cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

    ?>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, you do not have to develop any form yourself : phpMyAdmin, depending on its configuration *(i.e. `config.inc.php`)* will display an identification form, asking for a login and password.

To get that form, you should not use :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

But you should use :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

*(At least, that's what I have on a server which prompts for login/password, using a form)*

For more informations, you can take a look at the documentation :

- [Using authentication modes](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#authentication_modes)
- [Configuration](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#config), which states *(quoting)* :

> `'config'` authentication (`$auth_type
>   = 'config'`) is the plain old way: username and password are stored in
>   config.inc.php. 
> `'cookie'`
>   authentication mode (`$auth_type =
>   'cookie'`) as introduced in 2.2.3
>   allows you to log in as any valid
>   MySQL user with the help of cookies. 
>   
> Username and password are stored
>   in cookies during the session and
>   password is deleted when it ends.

Comment: thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. Youre the man!

Comment: After some time, they changed the link to the [authentication docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes)

Answer (score 3):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

should work.

From [**the manual**](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/auth_types):

> auth_type = 'cookie' prompts for a MySQL username and password in a friendly HTML form. This is also the only way by which one can log in to an arbitrary server (if $cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] is enabled). Cookie is good for most installations (default in pma 3.1+), it provides security over config and allows multiple users to use the same phpMyAdmin installation. For IIS users, cookie is often easier to configure than http.

Answer (score 2):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```