# how to get login option for phpmyadmin in xampp

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, xampp

when i open localhost/phpmyadmin/ in xampp it opens directly the home page with root as user but not a login page. My page looks same as in [here in this link](http://www.yourwebskills.com/dbphpmyadminusers.php)
how can I get a login page, what are the setting I should do to get a login page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you set the password to the phpmyadmin here

```
http://localhost/security/index.php
```

Comment: I have done some changes login page appears but I cannot see my home page now , it shows some error  MySQL said: Documentation

#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: how can one user can access its own database assigned to them?

Comment: found answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341504/how-to-configure-config-inc-php-to-have-a-loginform-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 65):

### Step 1:

Locate phpMyAdmin installation path.

### Step 2:

Open `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` in your favourite text editor. Copy `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php` if it's missing.

### Step 3:

Search for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

Replace it with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

Comment: i have another problem can u help

Comment: http://alandoyle.com/tutorials/configuring-phpmyadmin-for-multiple-users/ , I studied this link and did but its showing error when I am writing in sql query window

Comment: how can one user can access its own database assigned to them?

Answer (score 21):

Ya, it's **working fine**, but it can enter into localhost **without** entering password.

You can do it in another way by following these steps:

1. In the browser, type: localhost/xampp/
2. On the left side bar menu, click **Security.**
3. Now you can see the **subject table**, and below the **subject table** you can see this link:
      **http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php**.
   Click this link.
4. Now you can **set the password** as you want.
5. Go to the xampp folder where you installed xampp. Open the xampp folder.
6. Find and open the phpMyAdmin folder.
7. Find and open the config.inc.php file with Notepad.
8. Find the code below:

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
   ```
9. Replace it with the code below:

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
   ```
10. Save the file and run the localhost/phpmyadmin with the browser.

Comment: I got login option after your steps. I have skipped your steps from 1 to 4.

Comment: When I hit the url shows error - `Object not found!`

Answer (score 11):

You can use

1. Go browser & type **localhost/phpmyadmin/**
2. Go to **User accounts**
3. Edit privileges from marked bellow image in last options **root->localhost->   Yes->ALL PRIVILEGES->Yes-> Edit privileges**

Here is image like bellow
[image]

4. you can click on  **Edit privileges** last option above image
5. Then you can click on **Change password**. It shows enter password screen
6. Enter your **password & retype** your password in password the field
7. Then click on **GO**
8. Then Go to **XAMPP->xamppfiles->config.inc.php**
9. Open **config.inc.php** file & go to /* Authentication type */ sections
10. change **config to cookie**  & **type your password in ' ' in password** like bellow

    ```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your password';
    ```
11. Then save & type on browser **localhost/phpmyadmin/**
12. Enter your given password & enjoy

Comment: If you are setting `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` it will ask for a password on the login page, so there is no point putting the password in `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your password';` as it will just be ignored

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to go to the login page of phpmyadmin, click the "exit" button (the second one from left to right under the main logo "phpmyadmin").