# Ask for username and password while accessing phpMyAdmin xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I dont know why i am not being asked to enter username and password while accessing phpMyAdmin.
please let me know how can i get to asked for username and password for accessing phpMyadmin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get login option for phpmyadmin in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759776/how-to-get-login-option-for-phpmyadmin-in-xampp)

Answer (score 1):

try this if it fails try using your ports: my is 8080 apache

http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Use your 
username = root
password = "nothing".

then click login in